# Why is there no official character song for Homura and Mami?

Tags: madoka-magica, theme-song

Madoka has a character song titled "See You Tomorrow" (またあした, Mata Ashita) while Sayaka and Kyoko have a duet song titled "And I'm Home".

I just found out that Homura and Mami don't have a character song (from this [Puella Magi wiki page](http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Madoka_Magica_Music)) like Madoka, Sayaka, and Kyoko do. Are there any character songs for Homura and Mami? If there aren't, why didn't they make one for them?

**Added to clarify**, by character song I mean

> A song whose vocals are credited to the character or characters singing the song.

as per this question [What is a “character song”?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26036/2869)

Comment: You could associate Magia with Homura since it's the most played track when Walpurgisnacht is about and Homura's goal (pre Ultimate Madoka) is it's destruction (Walpurgisnacht normally being the cause of Madoka becoming a Magical Girl)

Comment: I heard that too, but why they don't make any official song for them?

Comment: probably because Magia wasn't sung by her seiyuu, the songs listed on the Wiki were sung by Madoka's, Kyoko's and Syayka's seiyuu, though this falls short as to answering your question which is why i've posted comments

Comment: No, but really consider this: Homura's character is too serious for a song. Mami… I don't know, maybe just nothing to sing about.

Comment: @user1306322 Homura maybe too series but what about Moemura?(Pre-Anime timeline), also with Mami she doesn't seem to have much to sing about because she isn't given much screen time in the anime as she dies early on or has a bout of insanity in a flashback. she only has a bit of a bigger role in Rebellion (but still, duet with Nagisa?)

Comment: Thought: Connect (the OP) is basically a character song for Homura if you think about it.

Comment: @senshin explain, i've always thought of it as an unofficial one for Madoka cause we see much more of her in the OP while Homura appears in like only 2 scenes and it also hints at the wish she made (the short where she's laying down withy a cat), given this is the TV Version i'm talking about which we see an Op which is very misleading anyway, i haven't seen what's on the PSP with the Game Installation Version

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure precisely how a character's "official" song is defined, but a ["Credens Justitiam"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MaQ6m6mho8) is, in my experience, often associated with Mami. Here's [one source](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/AwesomeMusic/PuellaMagiMadokaMagica) that sites this as the case. Further, for a more speculative approach, this is the song that plays during several of the scenes involving Mami, and, likewise,

> no longer seems to play in the anime after Mami dies (if memory serves me correctly).

Thus it would make sense that this is identified as her theme song.

As for Homura's song, the same source I listed earlier states that Homura's theme song is *"Puella in Somnio" ("The Girl in the Dream")*. Google searching "homura's theme" also will return several YouTube videos all of this song. As before, I believe this song is played most often (if not exclusively) in scenes directly involving or featuring Homura.

Comment: A _character song_ is one that is sung by the character in question. I agree that you could call "Credens Justitiam" a _theme song_ for Mami, but it is not a _character song_, since the vocals are not done by Mami (i.e. Fukuhara Kaori). Contrast "Mata Ashita", which is sung by Madoka, and "And I'm Home", which is sung by Sayaka and Kyouko.

Comment: @senshin Gotcha. I figured this answer was too easy to be what you were looking for! Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's a late answer...

> ## TL;DR Version
>
> **Character Songs**
>
> - Madoka Kaname: Mata Ashita
> - Homura Akemi: Connect
> - Mami Tomoe: Credens Justitiam
> - Sayaka Miki and Kyoko Sakura : And I'm Home

I would attribute **Credens Justitiam** track as being *Mami's* character song.

The **Connect** track is *Homura Akemi's* character song.

Indeed, this is not obvious, because it shows *Madoka Kaname* throughout the video; This is actually the perspective of *Homura* in the original universe, before she wished to become a magical girl. She had watched her friends(Madoka, Sayaka and Mami) protecting the city from *familiars and witches* as magical girls.
(Remember that *Kyoko* was introduced into the story only when *Mami* died...)

This is what consists of the video content of the opening **Connect** track.

The lyrics actually convey *Homura's* thoughts after she has lived through multiple time-lines and conveys that she will never hesitate to protect *Madoka*...

Also notice that it is played at the end of episode 12, supporting the fact that it is *Homura's* character song.

Credits to users *senshin* and *Secret Evil Radio* for their thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

there's a more recent song, Mebius Ash, sung by Chiwa Saito, so that's Homura's character song, i guess. released in the same album is Stairs, a duet song sung by  Kaori Mizuhashi and Ai Nonaka, but thats the only song that could count as Mami's character song.
source: https://wiki.puella-magi.net/Madoka_Magica_Soundtrack#Ultimate_Best (it says "An album released on August 8th, 2017, containing songs from the anime, the movies, and several songs that only appeared in the Pachinko and Pachislot games." so while the album itself was released in 2017, maybe whatever those are released prior to that?)
(also this has gotta be the worlds latest answer, i came along this while trying to find out if Mami had a character song lol)